# ROS fuerte PCL features, surface and segmentation libraries

Tags: pcl, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, perception-pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I started using fuerte on 12.04 and face this problem while migrating code from electric on 10.04. When I try to launch nodelets of type pcl/NormalEstimation and pcl/SACSegmentationFromNormals, I get errors saying libpcl_ros_features.so and libpcl_ros_segmentation.so cannot be found. I wasn't able to find these shared objects at /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/lib/.

```
[ERROR] [1352391653.634193667]: Failed to load nodelet [/normal_estimation] of type [pcl/NormalEstimation]: Failed to load library /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/lib/libpcl_ros_features.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/lib/libpcl_ros_features.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

[ERROR] [1352391655.206178336]: Failed to load nodelet [/cylinder_segmentation] of type [pcl/SACSegmentationFromNormals]: Failed to load library /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/lib/libpcl_ros_segmentation.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/lib/libpcl_ros_segmentation.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I looked up ROS answers and found the first comment for [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/32039/error-while-loading-nodelet-normal_estimation/?answer=32124#post-id-32124) pointed the issue and the fix. Following that, I uncommented the lines corresponding to features, surface and segmentation in the CMakeLists for pcl_ros package. When I rosmake the package after these changes I get errors, with respect to the setSearchMethod in pcl. The fix mentioned [here](http://www.pcl-users.org/Features-demo-code-from-PCL-Tutorial-at-RSS-2011-not-working-td3825109.html) worked for my other packages. But not here. I get this error as mentioned in [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/31844/inittree-method-in-perception_pcl-stack/).

There is a ticket regarding this bug, [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5426).

Any help on fixing this issue is much appreciated.

Thank you,
Harsha

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47814/ros-fuerte-pcl-features,-surface-and-segmentation-libraries/) by [harsha](https://answers.ros.org/users/3217/harsha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2012-11-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-11-08**:
Are `libpcl_ros_features.so` and `libpcl_ros_segmentation.so` actually present in that directory after you build `pcl_ros`?

**Comment by [harsha](https://answers.ros.org/users/3217/harsha/) on 2012-11-08**:
Hi Joq. I looked into /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/lib. They are not present in the directory. The libraries available are libgtest.a  libgtest_main.a  libpcl_ros_filters.so  libpcl_ros_io.so  libpcl_ros_tests.so  libpcl_ros_tf.so.

**Comment by [harsha](https://answers.ros.org/users/3217/harsha/) on 2012-11-08**:
When I try to build pcl_ros after uncommenting the lines for features and segmentation, the build fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your build is failing because you are using the /opt/ros/fuerte install tree. Due to file permissions, that can only be updated by the admin (root) user.

*Do not* try to build it there using the `sudo` command. That is *not* a good solution.

Instead, check out a [source overlay](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays) using `rosws` or some similar tool, and build it there. That version will take precedence over the one installed in /opt/ros/fuerte.

EDIT: The reason you should not *ever* make any changes in the /opt/ros trees is because future Debian package updates will destroy your work.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harsha](https://answers.ros.org/users/3217/harsha/) on 2012-11-09**:
Thanks for the reply. I understand using rosws is better. I changed the permissions of the pcl_ros package from root to user and tried to build. Should've mentioned it earlier. The errors are as mentioned [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/31844/inittree-method-in-perception_pcl-stack/)

**Comment by [harsha](https://answers.ros.org/users/3217/harsha/) on 2012-11-09**:
That's right. I would lose all the changes I made when I update the package. I'll remember that. Thanks for letting me know about rosws. I'll use it and let you know how it goes. I appreciate your help.